# Usage of preposition 'on' with verb like 'catch'

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, verbs, clauses

Regards, I would like to know about a particular usage of the preposition 'on'. The sentence

> What a pity, his house was on fire.

means that the house was damaged by a fire.

But the preposition 'on' is used for **time** and **place (surface)**. What explanation for this?

Now what about these two sentences :

> 1. The paper will catch with fire.
> 2. The paper will catch on fire.

Which is the correct sentence?

I would appreciate thorough and compact analysis. Thanks.

Comment: **On** is used for a lot more than just time or surfaces.  You can be **on duty** or **on the clock**, or give a speech **on a subject**, you can be **on time** to an event, you can change your mind after **reflecting on something**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on) lists about 25 meanings of **on**. Check out the link if you want to see examples of each usage.

Which preposition should you use in this context? Well, I would go for none at all: [catch fire](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/catch?q=catch%20fire) is an idiomatic expression. This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=catch%20fire%2Ccatch%20on%20fire%2C%20catch%20with%20fire&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccatch%20fire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccatch%20on%20fire%3B%2Cc0) shows that **catch fire** is considerably more common than **catch on fire**, and **catch with fire** gets no hits at all.

If you are concerned about the rationale for when to use **on** or not, you could have a look at some of the actual references that NGram found.